# How to do a discontinuos segmented logistic regression in R?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, piecewise-linear, segmented-regression

I'm trying to do a discontinuous segmented logistic regression, something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AO1Mh.jpg .
The 6 breaking points are predetermined from domain knowledge.
Unfortunately my textbook (ISLR) provides codes for the continuous one only.

After searching on the web, i stumbled on the 'segmented' package, and wrote this code:

```
fit = glm(is_legendary~pokedex_number, family = binomial, data = pokedex)

segfit = segmented(fit,seg.Z = ~pokedex_number, psi=c(151.5, 251.5, 386.5, 493.5, 649.5, 721.5))
```

and it gave me this error:

```
Error in seg.glm.fit(y, XREG, Z, PSI, w, offs, opz, return.all.sol = TRUE) : 
  dims [product 4] do not match the length of object [6]
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In id.psi.in & id.psi.far :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In id.psi.in & id.psi.far :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

am I using the correct package and function for my objective? If so, what caused the error?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using the `mcp` package. You specify the regression model on a segment-by-segment basis.

## Model

Let's say that the segments all have an intercept and a slope. Also, for the sake of simplicity, let's just deal with the case of four segments:

```
model = list(
  y ~ 1 + x,  # Segment 1
  ~ 1 + x,  # Segment 2
  ~ 1 + x,  # Segment 3
  ~ 1 + x  # Segment 4
)
```

## Simulate data

Let's make some toy data, using the change point values you provided. Here, I just simulate data as if the intercept and slope is identical in all segments, but this need not be so:

```
# Get object to simulate data from model
library(mcp)
empty = mcp(model, sample = FALSE, family = bernoulli())

# Simulate data
df = data.frame(x = 1:500)
df$y = empty$simulate(
  df$x,
  cp_1 = 151.5, cp_2 = 251.5, cp_3 = 386.5,
  int_1 = -3, int_2 = -3, int_3 = -3, int_4 = -3,
  x_1 = 0.04, x_2 = 0.04, x_3 = 0.04, x_4 = 0.04)
```

## Do regression

Now let's see if we can recover these values. You specify known change parameter values via the prior. So a simple version may be:

```
prior1 = list(cp_1 = 151.5, cp_2 = 251.5, cp_3 = 386.5)  # Constants - not inferred
fit1 = mcp(model, data = df, prior = prior1, family = bernoulli())
```

From your drawings, it seems that the sigmoids are highly similar, so if you want to add the constraint that the intercepts and slopes are identical, you can do this too:

```
prior2 = list(
  cp_1 = 151.5, cp_2 = 251.5, cp_3 = 386.5,  # Constants
  int_2 = "int_1", int_3 = "int_1", int_4 = "int_1",  # Shared
  x_2 = "x_1", x_3 = "x_1", x_4 = "x_1"  # Shared
)

fit2 = mcp(model, data = df, prior = prior2, family = bernoulli())
```

## Show results

Here is the plot of the fits using `plot(fit)`. Here they are for `fit1` (top) and `fit2` (bottom):

[image]

You can see parameter estimates using `summary(fit)` and `plot_pars(fit)`.

## Comments

You can see more on the [mcp website](https://lindeloev.github.io/mcp/) and the [mcp paper](https://osf.io/fzqxv/), including how to work with priors. Disclaimer: I am the author of `mcp`.

Naturally, the example above can be tinkered to meet your goal. For example, maybe you only know the location of a change point down to some level of uncertainty. In that case, put a narrow prior on it, e.g., `prior = list(cp_1 = "dnorm(151.5, 10)")`.